# Referencing a cell in query function not included in range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to write a query function that selects a value from a column on a different sheet where a different column from the same sheet is equal to a cell on the target sheet.

Here's my attempt at trying to show this with code:

`=QUERY(OtherSheet!D:E,"Select E where (D = D8)")`

D8 is the cell from the target sheet that I want to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be:

```
=QUERY(OtherSheet!D:E, "select E where D = "&D8)
```

if **D8** is a numeric value

---

otherwise, if **D8** is plain text it should be:

```
=QUERY(OtherSheet!D:E, "select E where D = '"&D8&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I would like to add that I'm trying to make this query continue to D9, D10, D11, etc. How can I do that without pasting the code into every cell of the target column?

Comment: it depends how your data looks like. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Nevermind, I 'compromised' and just pasted it into each cell of the target column. No biggie.

Comment: it's hard to guess but in most cases, your issue may be solvable with VLOOKUP